# fastest way for searching for an element inside a containing element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, contains

I have a small container elelement 'instructor-column' with about 100 lines of html and I can fetch the element like this

```
var instrCol = $(eventRow).find("div.instructor-column");
```

then I want to check if I have another element inside this element, kinda like this

```
var regThumb = $(instrCol).find("#registerThumbnailContainer");
```

so then I can check if it exists or not!

What's the best/fastest way to search for that element in the containing element?

I see different solutions but not sure which is the best/fastest!

I see..

```
$(eventRow).contains('someElement')
$(eventRow).hasClass('someClass')
```

I also see something like this

```
$(instrCol).find("#registerThumbnailContainer").length // not sure if this would work, but something similar
```

what's the best/fastest!?

Comment: Run some tests of your own and find out

Comment: how can I do that? What tools, Chrome debugger?

Comment: Sure. Also performance test sites like jsperf

Comment: cool thanks, I''l check it out!